# ssh to remote server is not working

Tags: linux, ssh, rhel, openssl

when app user tried to connect remote server via cmd `ssh <remote server dns>`, it is failing with

> error:Couldn't obtain random bytes (error 0x2d092087)

But other local users are able to connect without this error. How to solve this issue.

PFB detailed error:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 12: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xd427937067af02.ubscloud-prod.msad.ubs.net [10.216.148.21] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa1 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa1-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa2 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_rsa2-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/skyl_dev/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to xd427937067af02.ubscloud-prod.msad.ubs.net:22 as 'skyl_dev'
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_151033660)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_151033660)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_151033660)

Couldn't obtain random bytes (error 0x2d092087)
```

Comment: what app? this sounds is an error from that app you are talking about.

Comment: Is this on a _very old system_? Is it possibly related to https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=115767

Comment: doing ssh from linux vm to remote linux vm with userid which is being used by application.

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.9 (Maipo)

Comment: The error seems to come from OpenSSH code: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/entropy.c#L193  Most references to this error that I can find seems to indicate that nobody nowadays sees it in normal operation. You may want to explain how your app uses OpenSSH (since it is causing the system to run out of entropy).

Comment: then why only one user is unable to ssh. Other's able to .Not sure where openssh code implemented. Any way to solve ssh issue?